# How well does the NEF capture neuronal heterogeneity?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, nef

From what I understand of the [Neurogical Engineering Framework](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/research/nef.html) (NEF), groups of neurons are used to compute functions. However, I'm not clear if these calculations take into account neurons of different shapes/sizes and their attributes/uses in the brain. How well does the NEF capture heterogeneity and how is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To review how neurons encode information, please check out [these class notes](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tcstewar/syde556/blob/master/SYDE%20556%20Lecture%202%20Representation.ipynb) review encoding.

In those notes, you'll notice the intercept $J_{bias}$ and the maximum firing rate $\alpha$ are randomly selected when encoding functions in large populations of neurons. These variations can account for heterogeneity in attributes of neurons.